# Create member from external class

Tags: c++

I'm basically trying to initialize an external class to use it as member in all my methods.

What I tried:

- Initialize the member in the header file (Error: `error: 'RECV_PIN_1' is not a type`)
- Initialize it in the constructor (Now it's not available in my methods)

Here's my shortened code:

```
// Receiver.h
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "IRremote.h"

class Receiver {
public:
    Receiver();
    void tick();
private:
    static const int LED_PIN = 13;
    static const int RECV_PIN_1 = 11;
    static const int MAX_HEALTH = 1000;

    // [..]

    IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN_1); // this does not work

    // [..]
};


// Receiver.cpp
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "IRremote.h"
#include "Receiver.h"

Receiver::Receiver() {
    // [..]
}

void Receiver::tick() {
    checkHitIndicator();
    // if there is a result
    if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
        playerHitDetected(10);
        // receive the next value
        irrecv.resume();
    }
}
```

It would be nice if somebody could explain me how and why one would achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first approach will only work if your compiler supports C++11 in-class initialisation; and you need to initialise it with `=` or `{}`, since initialisation with `()` looks too much like a function declaration:

```
IRrecv irrecv{RECV_PIN_1};  // or
IRrecv irrecv = IRecv(RECV_PIN_1);
```

The second approach should be fine; I've no idea why it might not be available in your methods, as long as you've declared it (without initialisation) in the class definition

```
IRecv irrecv;
```

and initialised it in the constructor

```
Receiver::Receiver() : irrecv(RECV_PIN_1) {
    // [..]
}
```

Comment: Hi, the first approach is not supported by my compiler.
The second one throws a cryptic error `undefined reference to `IRrecv::IRrecv(int)'`

Comment: @JulianHollmann: The second should be, that's been standard since the dawn of time.

Comment: I updated my comment, the second approach also doesn't work for me

Comment: @JulianHollmann: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What was the error message? Did you do exactly as I described?

Comment: Here's my full terminal output: http://pastebin.com/BijDnamf
The errors with `undefined reference to` are the interesting ones.

Comment: @JulianHollmann: That means your're not defining the member functions of `IRecv`, or not linking with the file that defines them. It's got nothing to do with initialising the variable.